# Can't access nginx accessible on private ip but not on public ip

Tags: azure, curl, nginx, terraform

I'm creating resources using terraform and I have a node in the subnet 172.1.0.0 with no security group or rules assigned to the node; the node has two endpoints 22 and 80.

I used nmap to confirm that the ports are open and they are:

```
nmap -Pn -sT -p T:11 some-ingress.cloudapp.net

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-08 19:02 EAT
Nmap scan report for some-ingress.cloudapp.net (1.2.3.4
Host is up (0.31s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.34 seconds


nmap -Pn -sT -p T:80 some-ingress.cloudapp.net

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-08 19:02 EAT
Nmap scan report for some-ingress.cloudapp.net (1.2.3.4)
Host is up (0.036s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
```

I've installed nginx on the node and running `curl 172.1.0.4` and `curl 127.0.0.1` and `curl 0.0.0.0` gets me the default nginx page.

However running `curl <public ip>` or `curl <dns name>` hangs and I get a

`curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

My iptables rules are:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Why can't I possibly access nginx at the node's public ip?

The node is in a virtual network `172.1.0.0/16` and a subnet of `172.1.0.0/24` I can post the terraform configs if needed.